# Catching a single coordinate value from a maya object

Tags: python, mel

I am using python to write a Maya script and I would like to be able to get a single coordinate value from a Maya object or object component.

In this case, I would like to retrieve only the y-coordinate value from a control vertex called "curve1.cv[1]"

I know how to get the full group of coordinates with:

```
cmds.pointPosition("curve1.cv[1]")
or

cmds.getAttr("curve1.cv[1]")
```

but both of these return a group of float values for x,y, and z.  I would like to be able to return just a single float value for the y coordinate.

How can I do this?

-ps. this is my first post here and I am a beginner programmer.  I apologize if this is the wrong place to ask questions about MEL/Python scripting.

Answer (score 0):

```
# You can also use pointPosition or getAttr
xyz = cmds.xform ( "curve1.cv[1]", query = True, translation = True )

# Use array index: xyz[0]=x, xyz[1]=y, xyz[1]=z
print xyz[1]
```